# Is this Employer trying to scam me

Tags: scams, employment

I have just interviewed with a company on indeed. The website looked very legit. I emailed the employer and he eventually scheduled me for an interview. The red flags I noticed were:

- He never got ahold of my resume
- He already told me about compensation
- He was very hard to hear over the phone
- I also tried calling the company on my own and the number was not in service

I really need this job but I hope this company isn't one of those messing with people.

Comment: Did they invite you to an office to talk in person? Is there any other red flags such as "too good to be true" salary sort of thing?

Comment: I'm not sure if any of us can give you a conclusive answer, sorry. It might be worth reading through some of the old employment scam questions on here to get your own list of potential red flags together.

Comment: You might also try doing some research on the company, other than looking at its own web site.

Comment: A number being out of service is a bad sign in terms of you working for a company that's organized and has its ducks in a row, but it's not *necessarily* a sign of a scam.  Indeed, I would expect scammers to be *very careful* about ensuring the phone numbers they list ARE in service, and directed to someone who's in on the scam.  The question then is, scam or no scam, do you really want to work for a company that can't even keep their phone in service and/or website contact info up to date?

Comment: What was the actual description of the job and its duties? Did the interview cover things like working hours and who you would report to?

Comment: [Seems pretty fishy](https://www.scampulse.com/event-decor-factory-reviews).  I really like the two identical comments from different people "_So strange...I've been successfully working with them over 6 months. They pay on time and as it was said, I work normally through their business account._"  Pretty obviously the scammers trying to plant some doubt... but copying the same message was a poor call.

Comment: Phone lines can go temporarily out of Service through no fault of the company itself. Some of my customers had repeated problems with their SIP-Providers. Why not ask the company about the phone issue?

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely possible that this employment situation is a scam. It sounds like an unprofessional company at best. Although it is entirely possible that this company is offering a legitimate employment opportunity, they are going about the recruiting and hiring process in a very unprofessional way. It is pretty uncommon for a prospective employer to offer a job without asking for a resume. It is also very rare for compensation to be discussed before the first interview.

My best guess from what you've described is that this is possibly a real employment opportunity, but the company is very unprofessional and possibly even trying to hide the nature of what they really do. It could also be a scam designed to convince you to [pay without every actually getting the job](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0243-job-scams#Signs). The fact that the company's number was not in service is definitely a red flag and is very suspicious.

In your case, I would continue searching for other jobs, because it seems doubtful that this opportunity is a fully legitimate one. As difficult as finding a job can be, you will ultimately be better off working for a more professional organization. If an employment opportunity seems suspicious, it is best to remember the old adage: "If it sounds too good to be true, it probably is."